# SQLAlchemy set index on coalesce

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to set up an index for a table on the coalesce function, rather than on a column. I am using PostgreSQL and I am trying to achieve something like :

`create index t on tbl using btree (coalesce(ts_updated, '2002-08-08'))`

Anyone knows how can I achieve this with SQLAlchemy in the ORM framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLAlchemy doesn't support expression in index definitions yet, but it's a [planned feature](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/ticket/695). Right now you have to use [custom DDL (see examples in documentation)](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/schema.html#custom-ddl).